# How to center two columns using CSS?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to center two columns on my website but there are some problems. The result of every change is left position (see [picture](http://i46.tinypic.com/5tov7.jpg)). What am I doing wrong? Here's my CSS:

```
body {
    background - image: url("../img/gray.png");
}

#header {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 100px;
    background: #cc0000;
    text - align: center;
}

#wrapper {
    margin: 100px;
    width: 1280px;
}

#leftcolumn {
    float: left;
    background - image: url("../img/gray.png");
    margin: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 682px;
    width: 460px;
}

#rightcolumn {
    float: left;
    color: #333;
    border: 1px solid # ccc;
    background: #F2F2E6;
    margin: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 500px;
    width: 439px;
    display: inline;
    position: relative;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Please provide a jsfiddle, or similar. Probably need to use `auto` horizontal margins.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since the two columns' width is less than the width of the wrapper (i.e. 959px vs 1280px), you'll need to place the two columns inside a fixed width container:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="column_container">
        <div id="column1"></div>
        <div id="column2"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And then do something like:

```
#column_container {
    width: 959px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: It works! but there should be as @mookamafoob mentioned, margin: 100px auto

Comment: There's already a margin on the `#wrapper` element. This should be used in addition to that. Please see the updated answer.

Answer (score 3):

Without seeing it live, something like this should work:

```
#wrapper { 
   width: 1280px;
   margin:100px auto ;
}
```

But as has been mentioned, this will only center `#wrapper`. The columns don't fill the entire 1280 width so they are still left aligned in `#wrapper`.

Comment: @Fastkowy you can do this by `text-align:center;` so content in #wrapper will be centered