# How to center two columns using CSS without using a fixed width container?

Tags: html, css, alignment

I have seen [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14814745/how-to-center-two-columns-using-css) which answers how to center two columns given that you know the total width of both columns in pixels. What if I don't know that or don't want to hard code that? If I at any point want to change the width of the columns I need also to recalculate the with of the wrapper manually. It goes against [the DRY principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) and reduces maintainability.

So this is the example code. How do I modify it to get the two columns centered on an arbitrary-sized screen without specifying the total container width in pixels? (This code doesn't center at all)

```
<html>
    <style>
        .column {
            width: 100px;
            float: left;
            border: 1px green solid;
            margin: 10px;
        }
        .container: {
            margin:auto;
        }
    </style>
</html>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="column">qwerty</div>
        <div class="column">asdf</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`display:inline-block` your columns, and then you can set `text-align:center;` on your container

```
.column {
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px green solid;
  margin: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
}
.container {
  margin:auto;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dPZ7L/2/

Comment: What if `width:100px` on the columns is a requirement? Your solution collapses the width of the columns

Comment: @Nilzor it would be `display:inline-block;` in that case, updated the fiddle

Answer (score 1):

I don't agree with the premise of the question most of the time you need to know the width of whatever you are doing as you need to deal with responsiveness - otherwise your wrapper will always 100%. It's more maintainable to set a width on the wrapper once and then use percentages everywhere else. This means you can center you wrapper and then not worry about working out what the widths of your columns are e.g.

```
.wrapper{
 width: 300px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

.col1{
width: 50%;
float: left;
}

.col2{
width: 33.33%
float: left;
}
```

This is only an example. My favourite grid system uses this idea: https://github.com/stubbornella/oocss/wiki/grids

Comment: This is a good solution if it's text in the columns. Actually my use case involves custom graphical controls which have a fixed width (I didn't include it in the question because I didn't think it'd be relevant). mlefevre's suggestion will work better in my case

Comment: doesn't matter - you have to change your way of thinking - they do not have to have a fixed width you can size the inputs with percentages or ems too. Also box-sizing is quite important in all of this.

Comment: I understand what you're saying, and maybe I will change my controls to be percentage or em-sized at a later point in time. Both answers are good.